# discord.py Изображения

Tags: изображения, discord.py

подскажите как сделать так чтобы бот мог принимать изображение, например: пользователь кидает в чат картинку, а бот редактирует ее и скидывает в чат.

Comment: Что по этому поводу говорит документация?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что-то в этом роде:

```py
image = await ctx.message.attachments[0].save(fp=ctx.message.attachments[0].filename)  # Получаем первую картинку из сообщения, и сохраняем её.

...  # Здесь что-то делаем


await ctx.send(file = image)
```

Полезные ссылки по этой теме:

[класс discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html#discord.Message)

[датакласс discord.File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html#discord.File)

Comment: Спасибо большое